# Python directory structure issues and having multiple versions on 1 machine

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, anaconda, python-idle

I recently started learning python, with not comp sci background so I had some questions. FYI, I have a mac and I am using the IDLE 3.8.5 shell.

1. I use the command terminal on my mac and I see that I have both Python 2.7 and 3.8 so how do I know which version i am running?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqcOk.png)

2. I am confused by the directory structure of python; in my laptop, the python 3.8.5 folder is saved in applications. In a separate folder, there is another folder called python with 2.7. When I create .py files and save them using my python IDLE shell, I get errors when I try to import the same files. What are the rules regarding where the python directory has to be, and the modules (scripts) that I am creating as I go? Right now my scripts are in my documents folder and in the same folder, I have the python 3.8.5 folder, which I made a copy of from my applications folder.
3. What is the different between using python IDLE shell vs other things, like anaconda? I have seen tutorial videos where people use different learning environments and their displays look very different despite them all using python so I was wondering which is best and most conducive to learning for a beginner ?

These questions may be super elementary so thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm not that familiar with using python on mac, but is there a reason for having python 2.7 and 3.8 together on your system? I guess it is only confusing, certainly as a beginner to have both, since the coding is a bit different. (I would drop the 2.7.) Further, I personally don't have the most recent version of python since not all libraries I use are yet compatible with it (I have a 3.6 and 3.7 at the moment).

Comment: Thank you that helps!

Answer (score 0):

On Linux based systems you have two seperate python commands:

One for your Python-2.x version

```
python your_file.py
```

And one for your Python-3.x version:

```
python3 your_file.py
```

This also applies to pip (pip and pip3) and executing commands like this:

```
python -m      # for python2.x
python3 -m     # for python3.x
```

Comment: Also I´ve learned python with IDLE aswell, great for beginners because it doesn´t overwhelm you with things like a debugger etc. But after a bit of expirience I´d change to VS Code or PyCharm depending on whether you want a heavy IDE (Integrated Development Environment) or a lite text editor. There´s also Vim which I can totally recommend, but it´s not intuitive and requires a lot of practice but then it becomes the most powerful thing on planet earth.

Comment: Thanks! I'll be looking into PyCharm